# Repeatable classes in Angular 6

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular6, scss-mixins

When i make pack of classes i use mixins and % classes, like this in vars:

```
@mixin margin($value) {
    margin-top: $value;
    margin-bottom: $value;
    &-top {
        margin-top: $value;
    }
    &-bottom {
        margin-bottom: $value;
    }
}

%margin-none {
    @include margin(0px);
}
%margin-nano {
    @include margin(8px);
}
```

And then i can extend it in same names to use it on site:

```
$margins: (
    'none',
    'nano',
    'tiny',
    ...
);

@each $m in $margins {
    .margin-#{$m} {
        @extend %margin-#{$m};
        &-top {
            @extend %margin-#{$m}-top;
        }
        &-bottom {
            @extend %margin-#{$m}-bottom;
        }
    }   
}
```

Or in components:

```
@import '../../../vars';

  .profit_column {
      @extend %margin-small-top;
      @extend %margin-small-bottom;
  }
```

But, if i use % classes, there is too much repeatable classes when i run my local site:

[Too much same classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkc1V.png)

It is very annoying, yes after minify on prod they will gone, but now they really interfere. What i can di with it?

UPD I know, if i change %name-of-class to

```
@mixin-prepend1
@mixin-prepend2
@mixin-prepend3
```

it will help, but i dont want do it, cause the code will not be so elegant)

UPD2 And i can't use cycles for making mixins from massive: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/626